# Groovy encodeBase64() returning unexpected result for PNG image file

Tags: groovy, encode

I am trying to convert a PNG image file to Base64 encoding in Groovy.

Here is my code:

```
ImageFile = new File("D:/DATA/CustomScript/Logo.png").text; 
String encoded = ImageFile.getBytes().encodeBase64().toString();
```

I get the following as result:

iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAIQAAABPCAIAAAClCfqHAAAABGdBTUE**AALE/C/xh**BQAAAAlwSFlzAAAOwwAADsMBx2+oZAAAAQ1JREFUeF7t1KGRgwAURdFVyHQbSwOkKlrIoECDSwusoYgDcz97396Z/3eGUQxIMSDFgBQDUgxIMSDFgBQDUgxIMSDFgBQDUgxIMSDFgBQDUgxIMSDFgBQDUgxIMSDFgBQDUgxIMSDFgBQDUgxIMSDFgBQDUgxIMSDFgBQDUgxIMSDFgBQDUgxIMSDFgBQDUgzIE2IcxzHP87qu176tJ8T4/X7Lsuz7fu3b6k1BigEpBq**QYP2JAig**EpBqQYP2JAigEpBqQYP2JAigEpBqQYP2JAigEpBqQYP2JAigEpBq**QYP2JAigEp**BqQYP2JAnhNj27ZxHN/v9/f7vU5385wYn8/n9XoNwzBN03W6l/P8BwSpsfw4c1/6AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC

The same image when passed through https://www.base64encode.org/ gives this result:

iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAIQAAABPCAIAAAClCfqHAAAABGdBTUE**AALGPC/xh**BQAAAAlwSFlzAAAOwwAADsMBx2+oZAAAAQ1JREFUeF7t1KGRgwAURdFVyHQbSwOkKlrIoECDSwusoYgDc497396Z/3eGUQxIMSDFgBQDUgxIMSDFgBQDUgxIMSDFgBQDUgxIMSDFgBQDUgxIMSDFgBQDUgxIMSDFgBQDUgxIMSDFgBQDUgxIMSDFgBQDUgxIMSDFgBQDUgxIMSDFgBQDUgxIMSDFgBQDUgzIE2IcxzHP87qu176tJ8T4/X7Lsuz7fu3b6k1BigEpBq**QYkGJAig**EpBqQYkGJAigEpBqQYkGJAigEpBqQYkGJAigEpBqQYkGJAigEpBq**QYkGJAigEp**BqQYkGJAnhNj27ZxHN/v9/f7vU5385wYn8/n9XoNwzBN03W6l/P8BwSpsfw4c1/6AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC

I have tried to **highlight** some of the differences. It is clear that both encoded strings are different.

Problem is that I have to pass this image's Base64 encoding to another system and it is accepting the one from https://www.base64encode.org/ but rejecting the one generated by Groovy.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer from user [cfrick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3181392/cfrick) was extremely helpful. Unfortunately, it didn't solve my problem. I believe the reason was that I was on an older version of Groovy.

This code eventually solved my problem:

```
String base64Image = "";
File file = new File(imagePath);
FileInputStream imageInFile = new FileInputStream(file);
byte[] imageData = new byte[file.size()];
imageInFile.read(imageData);
base64Image = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(imageData);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are hiting an encoding problem here.  Binary data is not character data; character data is effected by encodings.  Instead of `text` use the `bytes` of the file.  E.g.

```
def f = "/tmp/screenshot-000.png" as File
assert f.bytes.encodeBase64().toString()==("/tmp/encoded_20190208131326.txt" as File).text
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I actually thought about this too but for some reason the system I am working in (Teradata CRM) always give an error if I try to use "bytes" directly without using "text" first. Not sure why :@ 

The error is too long to post here but starts like this: 

[org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:49), org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.GetEffectivePojoPropertySite.getProperty(GetEffectivePojoPropertySite.java:63), org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:237)